# Selecting single country and getting statistics in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am a new QGIS user and have the following problem:
I have a Raster-source (Map of lightpollution worldwide) and want to select single countrys and see the specific statistics concerning this country.

Is this possible and if it is, how?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as zonal statistics, where each country represents a zone over which the statistics will be calculated. See [QGIS Zonal Statistics Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html) and [Tutorial for raster sampling in QGIS](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/sampling_raster_data.html).

In your case, in addition to the raster of light pollution, you would also need a polygon/raster layer indicating the boundaries of countries you are interested in.